# How to fix [!] No podspec found for `flutter_test` in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_test/ios`

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I've been using flutter and there's no error like this until yesterday. But when I launch the simulator, I got the message below.

```
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Exited (sigterm)
```

So I was looking for solutions, and then I modified pod.file in iOS folder.
After `pod update` in terminal, I can see the message "[!] No podspec found for `flutter_test` in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_test/iOS`".

`pod install` doesn't work, and I have no idea why this error occurs. 
It looks like I have to change something in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_test/iOS`, but still I can't find directions about that. Please anyone show me how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you've changed the plugin's name manually and forget to change the name of .podspec file.

[image: You should change this name too]

You can find the podspec file from the `ios` folder of your plugin.

Dont' forget clean the plugins cache and re-get it. Make sure this file from the cache is renamed.

Comment: How do you clean the plugins cache and re-get it?

Comment: @M.Leonhard The most simple way is to comment the dependency from the pubspec.yaml file, `pub get`, then umcomment it and do `pub get` again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with erasing unused plugins of `pubspec.yaml`. I'll leave this here for the people who met the same error.